# Charged particle in uniform Magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, charge

How can charged particle have constant kinetic energy in uniform magnetic field. I mean particle is accelerating so it must radiate EMW and loose energy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A charged particle in a magnetic field only has constant kinetic energy only if radiative losses are ignored. Indeed, as you correctly pointed out, a particle will lose energy due to radiation as it is accelerated by the magnetic field. However, radiative effects are typically suppressed by several powers of $c$ (by the Larmor formula), so at nonrelativistic speeds, kinetic energy is very nearly constant.

Comment: So, do we have formula for how much radiation energy emitted by accelerating charge, if then what is it?

Comment: Yes, the [Larmor formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula) supplies the power radiated by a nonrelativistic accelerating charge.