# Charged particles deflected by gravitational and magnetic fields

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, gravity, magnetic-fields, charge, grand-unification

I am trying to better understand one of my previous questions, and another.

[Charged particle in uniform Magnetic field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/473452)

[Does a charged particle orbiting Earth radiate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/797881)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_radiation_of_charged_particles_in_a_gravitational_field

To the extent I understand the answers, it seems to me that a charged particle behaves differently if it is deflected by a gravitational or a magnetic field.

Even though the particle follows the exact same trajectory, it behaves differently.

In a magnetic field, it is a clear-cut radiation. If I lived in an almost massless magnetic field that mimics Earth's gravitational field on a very big scale (obviously, the magnetic dipolarity is an issue, so maybe mimic Earth's gravity in one half of the space), I could see the charged particles coming from the Sun radiating (with appropriate sensors).

In a gravitational field, there is a radiation, but it is hidden away by an event horizon from an observer on the surface of the Earth.

Could it be that a gravitational field is like a magnetic field and then something, something extra?

What does this tell us about the feasibility of a Grand Unified theory involving gravity?

Comment: No new theories are needed to explain this. GR does it. To reiterate JEB's comment from your previous queston - This is a well known paradox. Any answer I could give would be copy pasta from: [Paradox of radiation of charged particles in a gravitational field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_radiation_of_charged_particles_in_a_gravitational_field)

Comment: To get back to this question, You say that a magnetic field fundamentally different from gravity, never to be unified? Or not? This question revolves around the difference between a magnetic and a gravitational field, and if there is a difference between the two, if a charged particle goes on the same trajectory by one or another. Do I need GR to explain a charge particle traversing a magnetic field?